# simplexml & php: read a node's value

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm running this code in php

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test_info.xml");
$xml_image = $xml->channel->userinfo->image;
```

test_info.xml:

```
<channel>
 <userinfo>
  <image>somewhere</image>
 </userinfo>
</channel>
```

it should return -somewhere- as it's `<image>`'s content, but it's returning a blank output. What am I doing wrong? I cant find anything better.

Answer (score 3):

Leave out `<channel>`, it's represented by `$xml`.

```
$xml_image = $xml->userinfo->image;
```